# Embed R Variable in Shiny HTML

Tags: r, bootstrap-4, shiny

Below are three files to illustrate my question and the way my program is structured. What I want to do is use the bootstrap card and within it put an R variable (e.g., the result of some calculation). Is there a way I can do that with the HTML in a separate document?

For example, suppose `myVariable <- 2^2` is done within the server file and I want the result of that calculation in the object myVariable to be inside the card where I've denoted "put R variable".

Thank you for advice or suggestions.

#### A simple ui.R file

```
ui <- fluidPage(
navbarPage(
theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "flatly"),
title = 'Methods',
tabPanel('One'),
),
mainPanel(
h1('Hello World'),  
includeHTML("foo.html")
)
)
```

#### A basic server.R file

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
server <- function(input, output) {
}
```

#### Contents of foo.HTML

```
<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-header">
    Featured
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
    <p class="card-text">I want to put an R variable here</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer text-muted">
    2 days ago
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the card comes from your custom HTML, not standard card components from Shiny or other Shiny extension packages. We can use `shinyjs` package to send the variable to UI and run some simple Javascript to update the value.

```r
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(shinyjs)
ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    navbarPage(
        theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "flatly"),
        title = 'Methods',
        tabPanel('One'),
    ),
    mainPanel(
        h1('Hello World'),  
        HTML(
            '
            <div class="card text-center">
              <div class="card-header">
                Featured
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                <p id="mycard" class="card-text">I want to put an R variable here</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                2 days ago
              </div>
            </div>
            '
        )
    )
)

library(shiny)
library(bslib)
server <- function(input, output) {
    observe({
        myVariable <- 2^2
        runjs(paste0('$("#mycard").text("', myVariable, '")'))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

1. I added an ID for the card `mycard` so I can easily selected with JS.
2. For easy to reproduce, I changed your *foo.html* to a `HTML()` tag, which is the same, you can continue to use your *foo.html*, but remember to add `id="mycard"` to the card.
3. So here you didn't give us under what condition the update is triggered, so I directly computed the value from server and send to UI update at start. Change according to your real case.

[image]

Comment: this works nicely and I could use this code directly! I'm not quite following the point (2)? If I put  <p id="mycard" class="card-text">I want to put an R variable here</p> in my foo.html file, it doesn't render the value. Did I put the id in the right place?

Comment: It worked on my end. I added the ID to the `p` tag in the foo.html and it worked fine. Try to use a fresh R session. When you use `includeHTML` you don't add `HTML` part. You should choose only one of them. Another thing is to check if you have added multiple `id="mycard"`. In HTML, ids must be unique.

Comment: Confirming this is good and I marked it as correct answer. It works in both ways as @lz100 suggests. I had a small error (forgot to put useShinyjs()) in my ui. Good suggestion and thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `renderUI`, in this way there's no need of **shinyjs**:

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

mycard <- function(x){
  sprintf('
  <div class="card text-center">
    <div class="card-header">
      Featured
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
      <p class="card-text">%s</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
      2 days ago
    </div>
  </div>
  ', x)
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(
    theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "flatly"),
    title = 'Methods',
    tabPanel('One'),
  ),
  mainPanel(
    h1('Hello World'),
    uiOutput("mycard")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  
  output[["mycard"]] <- renderUI({
    HTML(mycard(2*2))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```